# Google App engine with Django and dajaxice

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-forms, dajax

i have created django project and i am deploying it on appengine.
In project i have created a demo using [dajaxice](http://www.dajaxproject.com/) ,
 It is running sucessfuly using  using following command,

```
python manage.py runserver
```

But when i am trying to run project using

```
./dev_appserver.py project-name
```

It is not working , and following error is shown in java-script console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Dajaxice is not defined
```

What wrong i am doing here please help me.
Thanks.

Here is the directory structure,

[image]

### Source Code is

***Settings.py***

```
# Django settings for testing project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '_tdda6+4y@l@^lc56+)(7d6ai_i!9b%aargo%au19!naw9#c0e'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testing.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testing.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
                 'templates',
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'dajaxice',
    'simple',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
STATICFILES_FINDERS = ("django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
                       "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
                       "dajaxice.finders.DajaxiceFinder")

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                               "django.core.context_processors.debug",
                               "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
                               "django.core.context_processors.media",
                               "django.core.context_processors.static",
                               "django.core.context_processors.request",
                               "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")
```

***Ajax.py***

```
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
from django.utils import simplejson


@dajaxice_register(method='GET')
@dajaxice_register(method='POST', name='other_post')
def hello(request):
    return simplejson.dumps({'message': 'hello from Nisangt'})


@dajaxice_register(method='GET')
@dajaxice_register(method='POST', name="more.complex.bye")
def bye(request):
    raise Exception("PUMMMM")
    return simplejson.dumps({'message': 'bye'})


@dajaxice_register
def lol(request):
    return simplejson.dumps({'message': 'lol'})


@dajaxice_register(method='GET')
def get_args(request, foo):
    return simplejson.dumps({'message': 'hello get args %s' % foo})
```

***views.py***

```
# Create your views here.
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render

from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_functions


def index(request):

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

***index.html***

```
{% load dajaxice_templatetags %}
<html>
<head>
{% dajaxice_js_import %}
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="Dajaxice.simple.hello(function(d){alert(d.message);})">Hello</button>
    <button onclick="Dajaxice.simple.bye(function(d){alert(d.message);})">Bye</button>
    <button onclick="Dajaxice.more.complex.bye(function(d){alert(d.message);})">Complex Bye</button>
    <button onclick="Dajaxice.simple.lol(function(d){alert(d.message);})">LOL</button>
    <button onclick="Dajaxice.simple.get_args(function(d){alert(d.message);}, {'foo': 'var'})">GET args</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No-one is going to download an unknown zip file from a dodgy hosting provider to see what your problem is. Please extract the smallest relevant bit of code that displays the problem, and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I think dajaxice creates .js file to upload to the browsers. 
Google app engine does not allow dajaxice to do this so you never get the js file.
I'm looking for a way to pre-compile and upload to google app engine.